# Binary data to date/time stamp, unable to find the proper conversion using Python

Tags: python, binary-data

First post, long time lurker, couldn't get the format the way I wanted it to be. -sorry

I'm trying to convert part of a binary file to a date/time (in Python). But whatever I try I'm unable to find the proper conversion.

My guess is that the left byte (`0x30`) is not part of the data, and the remaining 8 bytes contain the relevant data.

Below are the binary parts, both in decimal and in Hex, and the date/time they represent. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
48  101 26  235 227 242 150 197 65
30  65  1a  eb  e3  f2  96  c5  41  
  -- should read as 16 December 2023 at 15:03

48  198 54  133 112 138 151 197 65
30  c6  36  85  70  8a  97  c5  41 
  -- should read as 17 December 2023 at 12:37

48  74  38  27  107 41  116 196 65
30  4a  26  1b  6b  29  74  c4  41 
  -- should read as 1 October 2022 at 12:49
```

I've tried to unpack the data as either double or long long int and then obtain a date from it. I've searched the site and tried chat GPT to no avail.

**Extra sample data**

```
30  23  84  b1  a8  b5  97  c5  41 : 17 December 2023 at 18:45
30  3f  91  e7  96  b5  97  c5  41 : 17 December 2023 at 18:45 (slightly later)
30  a6  d6  2f  d1  b5  97  c5  41 : 17 December 2023 at 18:46
30  e8  16  9c  b9  b5  97  c5  41 : 17 December 2023 at 18:47
```

Comment: Have you considered little Vs big Endian?

Comment: yes, and shifting the bytes around / breaking them up in 2 4byte pairs

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the serialising process. What language/function/process dumped those timestamp?

Comment: it are log files, but I have no idea what language/function created the timestamp

Comment: Do you know the timezone, by any chance? Also, do you have some more examples, e.g. close-by consecutive times? BTW, you may just provide all examples as a dict `{'hex': 'timestr', ...}` such as `'30 4a 26 1b 6b 29 74 c4 41': '1 October 2022 at 12:49'`; there is no need for the decimal version.

Comment: Here you go, not sure if and where a timezone correction takes place, but my time zone is CET (and so are the displayed times) More lines added to the original post, comments mess up the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I asked in comments for some more examples, especially ones close to each other by time, was to see what parts in the binary values were changing. I considered several types of encoding (some even based on textual representations of the timestamps). I looked at [`temporenc`](https://temporenc.org/). I looked at floating point representations of seconds since the Epoch.

But one thing struck me: it was quite interesting to see that among these three examples:

```py
{
    '30 65 1a eb e3 f2 96 c5 41': '16 December 2023 at 15:03',
    '30 c6 36 85 70 8a 97 c5 41': '17 December 2023 at 12:37',
    '30 23 84 b1 a8 b5 97 c5 41': '17 December 2023 at 18:45',
}
```

the `c5` byte (2nd from right) is constant, while the 3rd byte from the right is `97` for `Dec. 17` and `96 for Dec. 16`.

Further, I started looking at the whole integer value of the bytes in reverse order (excluding the first and last ones that are constant and may be delimiters).

I then noticed that the time differences between two consecutive timestamps corresponded to a multiple of the `int` values. That multiple is close to `8_388_608`, which is `2 ** 23`.

Fast-forward to a few more steps, and we get:

```py
def f(k):
    return (int(''.join(k.split()[1:-1][::-1]), 16) >> 23) - 4927272860
```

That function gives a fairly good approximation of the timestamps provided, in seconds since the Epoch. One additional thing is, there was a conspicuous 3600 seconds error for the October date, so I figured there was some daylight savings in your dates. Since you are in Europe, I used Zurich's timezone.

Put all together:

```py
import pandas as pd


tz = 'Europe/Zurich'

examples = {
    '30 65 1a eb e3 f2 96 c5 41': '16 December 2023 at 15:03',
    '30 c6 36 85 70 8a 97 c5 41': '17 December 2023 at 12:37',
    '30 4a 26 1b 6b 29 74 c4 41': '1 October 2022 at 12:49',
    '30 23 84 b1 a8 b5 97 c5 41': '17 December 2023 at 18:45',
    '30 3f 91 e7 96 b5 97 c5 41': '17 December 2023 at 18:45:30',
    '30 a6 d6 2f d1 b5 97 c5 41': '17 December 2023 at 18:46',
    '30 e8 16 9c b9 b5 97 c5 41': '17 December 2023 at 18:47',
}

examples = dict(sorted([
    (k, pd.Timestamp(v, tz=tz)) for k, v in examples.items()
], key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Then:

```py
def f(k):
    return (int(''.join(k.split()[1:-1][::-1]), 16) >> 23) - 4927272860

def to_time(k, tz):
    return pd.Timestamp(f(k) * 1e9, tz=tz)

fmt = '%F %T %Z'

test = [
    (
        f'{v:{fmt}}',  # given time
        f'{to_time(k, tz=tz):{fmt}}', # estimate from bytes
        (to_time(k, tz=tz) - v).total_seconds(), # difference in seconds
    )
    for k, v in examples.items()
]

>>> test
[('2022-10-01 12:49:00 CEST', '2022-10-01 12:49:30 CEST', 30.0),
 ('2023-12-16 15:03:00 CET', '2023-12-16 15:03:23 CET', 23.0),
 ('2023-12-17 12:37:00 CET', '2023-12-17 12:36:37 CET', -23.0),
 ('2023-12-17 18:45:00 CET', '2023-12-17 18:45:25 CET', 25.0),
 ('2023-12-17 18:45:30 CET', '2023-12-17 18:44:49 CET', -41.0),
 ('2023-12-17 18:46:00 CET', '2023-12-17 18:46:46 CET', 46.0),
 ('2023-12-17 18:47:00 CET', '2023-12-17 18:45:59 CET', -61.0)]
```

Perhaps with more examples and more info, you may adjust the constants used above. I tried to express the offset above in terms of an origin as a date, but it wasn't satisfying. One approach I tried was with:

```py
origin = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-05 18:48:33')
offset = int(origin.value / 1e9)

def f(k):
    return (int(''.join(k.split()[::-1])[3:-2], 16) >> 23) + offset
```

but I didn't find it much better from an "Occam's razor" perspective.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @Pierre D, this did the trick!